# Unexpected result when indexing a multidimensional List in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm getting a strange result when indexing a multi-dimensional list. Take the following for example:

```dart
void main() {
  var multiList = new List.filled(4, new List.filled(4, "x"));
  print(multiList);
  // [[x, x, x, x], [x, x, x, x], [x, x, x, x], [x, x, x, x]]
  multiList[2][1] = "A";
  print(multiList);
  // [[x, A, x, x], [x, A, x, x], [x, A, x, x], [x, A, x, x]]
  // Expected result:
  // [[x, x, x, x], [x, x, x, x], [x, A, x, x], [x, x, x, x]]
}
```

When I try to replace index [2][1] with a value, the value is placed in all the sub-Lists.

Do you know why this is happening? How can I get the expected result instead?

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use `generate` instead of `filled`

```dart
var multiList = new List.generate(4, (i) => new List.filled(4, "x"));
```

otherwise only one `new List.filled(4, "x")` is created and inserted 4 times. If you add a non-primitive type in the inner list then use generate there too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That solved my problem and the explanation makes sense, too. Thanks!